# Using NOT operator with AddressOf in a LINQ Where

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm wondering if there's a way to use the Boolean NOT operator in a LINQ Where statement when using it with a referenced method as its function, as I consider it good programming practice to always have methods or Boolean tests check for a positive whenever possible (eg, it's best to name a boolean variable/method *IsHappy* or *IsMad*, not *NotIsHappy*)

So far I have the following code:

```
Dim DynClass As Object
Dim propInfos As List(Of PropertyInfo)
...
'determine all our current properties which are not primitives or strings
propInfos = DynClass.GetType.GetProperties.Where(AddressOf NotIsPrimitiveOrStringType).ToList
```

And then the methods referenced by the Where:

```
Public Function IsPrimitiveOrStringType(p As PropertyInfo) As Boolean
    Return Not p.PropertyType.IsPrimitive And Not p.PropertyType.Name = GetType(String).Name
End Function
Public Function NotIsPrimitiveOrStringType(p As PropertyInfo) As Boolean
    Return Not IsPrimitiveOrStringType(p)
End Function
```

DynClass can be any object, and is passed in to the method.

Is there a more elegant way to do this, since I will need to reuse the IsPrimitiveOrStringType feature elsewhere in my application?

Comment: I suppose I could just call it _IsComplexType_, but I still feel like there may be a principle I'm missing in using NOT with AddressOf.

Comment: And actually, I have a semantic error in there with my boolean operators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [Lambda expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531298.aspx) in order to use the normal `Not` operator:

```
propInfos = DynClass.GetType.GetProperties.Where(Function(p) Not IsPrimitiveOrStringType(p)).ToList
```

Comment: Cool, that's nice and simple. I originally had the expression in _IsPrimitiveOrStringType_ as a Lambda, but I wanted to reuse it elsewhere, so I made it into a function in my class. It didn't occur to me that I could simply call another function that way.Thanks!